# What's the topology on the mapping space $Map_H(G, Y)$ when $G$ is not finite

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups, equivariant

When $G$ is a finite group and $H$ a closed subgroup of it, the sets of right cosets $H\backslash G$  has the discrete topology on it. Let $Y$ be a $H-$space. We have the $G-$homeomorphism \begin{equation}\mbox{Map}_H(G,
Y)\cong \prod_{H\backslash G}Y.\end{equation} Fix a family of
representatives $\{b_{\tau}\}_{\tau\in H\backslash G}$ of the
right cosets of $H$ in $G$.  For any $g\in G$, there is a unique
$b_{\tau}$ and $h''\in H$ such that $g=h''b_{\tau}$. The
homeomorphism is defined by $$f\mapsto (f(b_{\tau}))_{\tau\in
H\backslash G}.$$ The left $G-$action on
$\prod\limits_{H\backslash G}Y$ is defined by
\begin{equation}g\cdot (y_{\tau})_{\tau\in H\backslash
G}=(h_{\tau'}y_{\tau'})_{\tau\in H\backslash
G},\end{equation} where for each $\tau\in H\backslash
G$, there is a unique $\tau'\in H\backslash G$ and unique
$h_{\tau'}\in H$ s.t. $Hb_{\tau}g=Hb_{\tau'}$,
$b_{\tau}g=h_{\tau'}b_{\tau'}$.

If $G$ is a compact Lie group, $H$ a closed subgroup of it and $Y$ a $H-$space, we still have the injection  \begin{equation}\mbox{Map}_H(G,
Y)\longrightarrow\prod_{H\backslash G}Y\end{equation} by sending a map $f$ to $$\{f(b_{\tau})\}_{\tau\in H\backslash G}.$$ But it may not be surjective because the topology on $G/H$ may not be discrete.

How can I see the topology on the mapping space $Map_H(G, Y)$? What condition a map $f$ should satisfy regarding the topology? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following is helpful:

If the $H$-action on $Y$ is trivial, then $Map_H(G,Y)\cong Map(H\backslash G,Y)$.

This generalizes to the following: $G\times_H Y \to H\backslash G$ is a fiber bundle with fiber $Y$ whose space of sections is $Map_H(G,Y)$. Note the special case of trivial $H$-action giving a trivial bundle.

Comment: Thank you very much. Where can I find more information about this fact? I'm trying to construct a $H-$map from $G$ to $Y$ so that its restriction to the fixed point space $(H\backslash G)^g$ by $g$ is a given map. I have no good idea how to make the extension continuous.

Comment: Just one more question. I also need to work on the space like $Map_H(G, Y)^K$, the fixed point space of $Map_H(G, Y)$ by another closed subgroup $K$ of $G$. Can you also interpret this fixed point space using sections and vector bundle? Thanks.